# Sequelize read dates in local timezone or given timezone

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2

I have set the timezone option to my config. To read time in local timezone I use `useUTC` to `false`. This was working. Currently this ain't working anymore. Throwing an warning when project starts as

> Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: useUTC.
>   This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an
>   error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration options to a
>   Connection

my configuration looks something like this:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER,process.env.DB_PASS,{
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    timezone: process.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '+06:00' : '+02:00',
    dialectOptions: {
        useUTC: false, //for reading from database
        dateStrings: true,
        typeCast: true,
        timezone: new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
    },
})
```

I know this question was asked before. I found that `useUTC:false` to read from database from stack overflow. But Now it's no longer working. Now I am getting datetime as Utc. I am using mysql2 package from npm.